# Is there a way to force update of the notes app or calendar app on macOS 10.12.5 Sierra?

Tags: calendar, notes.app

I'm having a problem with the notes app and/or the calendar app. Is there a way to force an update/replace of either of these apps.  Maybe that will solve my problem.

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: This sounds to me like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please describe the actual problem you are having so we can give you an appropriate answer.

Comment: I put in a question about this several weeks ago but got no answer. If I create a new note in my notes app the calendar opens to current month,  So if I'm in a hurry, like making a note during a phone conversation, I have to wait while calendar opens.  I would normally laugh about this but its become frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Apple does not offer any method of replacing or updating individual default applications. The only way to do this would be to perform a reinstall. Your issue is certainly unusual, but a reinstall will most likely take care of it. Note that a reinstall will not touch your personal data.

Comment: Thanks for info about not losing my previous notes. I have lots of important info stored there.  Now for the stupid question: how do I reinstall 10.12.5?

Comment: The easiest way is to reboot into Recovery by rebooting while holding down `command + r`, and follow the onscreen instructions.